# How to set original image for animate background image in css

Tags: html, css, animation

**css code:**

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #slideshow {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #animate-area { 
        height: 100%;
        width: 2538px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-image: url('http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png');

        -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    }
    /* Put your css in here */
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cz04c4nx/2/

Now animation is working smoothly, but image size not show as original.
Now set my original image for animate?..for that,when i adjust background-position or width and height, animation is not working properly, ..

can anybody help me with us, Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question...is the picture too small? How tall should it be?

Comment: @BrianBennett: I want to adjust the height of image.. and remove the black space.

Comment: the black spaces is from the Image you can remove them by photoshop

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers: My original image is not have black space..when run background:url('../img/banner.png'); will show original image, when run background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png'); will show block space .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your image doesn't look bigger because the original file is only 100px tall. If you want to make it taller without losing quality, you'll need a larger source image for your script.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz04c4nx/6/) for the method described below.

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) has a good tutorial for getting good full-screen (or full-div) images, and you can use that method here.

First, set the height of your `#animate-area`

```
#slideshow {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 400px; /* Or whatever height you want */
    }
```

Then, add `repeat-x` to the `background` tag as well as adding the `background-size` attribute:

```
#animate-area {
    background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png') repeat-x;
    background-size:cover;
    .... /* Other CSS */
}
```

But, like I said, until you have a higher-res image, this won't look so great.

Comment: nope, @Brian Bennett. my original image size: 175px.

Comment: When I look at your source image, [this is what I see](http://www.screencast.com/t/1VgZwWzywnK). You need to edit your question with that information (175px high) so answers are more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

is that what u want ?

http://jsfiddle.net/cz04c4nx/7/

if so u have to add another parent to handle the slider

```
 <div id="slideshow">
     <div id="fixme">
        <div id='animate-area'>
        </div>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: yes, with this same animation, need to increase height of image, from my original image size is 175px,